# Finding Exact Value of a Region enclosed by 2 curves

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

Given Question:

Consider the functions f(x)=ax<sup>2</sup>-x+1 and g(x)=-x<sup>2</sup>+10x+3. For each a>0, let R(a) be the area enclosed by the curves y=f(x) and y=g(x). Find the unique value a>0 such that R(a)=  1257728/3213675. I have to put into exact value.

From my understanding:
I can see it's going to be some two quadratic equations and it gives an enclosed region, which has already given the region area of 1257728/3213675. However, I'm having trouble finding the unique value for "a"

What I so far did

```
 f = a*x^2 - x + 1;
 g = -x^2 + 10 x + 3;
 Plot[{f, g}, {x, -5, 10}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

but it doesn't plot anything since a is unknown. Maybe some iteration is required but I'm not familiar with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

First, find the intersection points of the two parabolas, since those will be our limits of integration later:

```
left = x /. First @ Solve[{(-x^2 + 10 x + 3) - (a x^2 - x + 1) == 0,
                           x < 0, a > 0}, x] // Simplify[#, a > 0] &
   (11 - Sqrt[129 + 8 a])/(2 + 2 a)

right = x /. First @ Solve[{(-x^2 + 10 x + 3) - (a x^2 - x + 1) == 0,
                            x > 0, a > 0}, x] // Simplify[#, a > 0] &
   (11 + Sqrt[129 + 8 a])/(2 + 2 a)
```

(Note how I imposed constraints in `Solve[]` to get the solution I want.)

From here, we set up the integral expression for the area:

```
area = Assuming[a > 0,
                Simplify[Integrate[(-x^2 + 10 x + 3) - (a x^2 - x + 1),
                                   {x, left, right}]]]
   (129 + 8 a)^(3/2)/(6 (1 + a)^2)
```

(note again the imposition of the constraint)

Finally, we use `Solve[]` again to get the required value of `a`:

```
a /. First @ Solve[{area == 1257728/3213675, a > 0}, a]
   1027/8
```

To check: use this value of `a` to get the corresponding integration limits:

```
{left, right} /. a -> 1027/8
   {-4/45, 4/23}
```

Plot the region:

```
Plot[{1027 x^2/8 - x + 1, -x^2 + 10 x + 3}, {x, -4/45, 4/23}]
```

Find the extremes:

```
{MinValue[1027 x^2/8 - x + 1, x], 1027 x^2/8 - x + 1 /. x -> 4/23}
   {1025/1027, 2491/529}
```

and then use `Area[]` + `ImplicitRegion[]`:

```
Area[ImplicitRegion[1027 x^2/8 - x + 1 <= y <= -x^2 + 10 x + 3,
                    {{x, -4/45, 4/23}, {y, 1025/1027, 2491/529}}]]
```

which should yield the expected answer.